# Free PIC C compiler

Tags: pic

I am looking for a free, and possibly open source C compiler for PIC. I might go without C, but I would like to get both options.

There are various compilers out there, but since I have never done PIC development before, I am looking for user experience and advice. I am targetting the PIC16F88x family

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030985/

Answer (score 13):

Try SDCC - an open source Small Device C Compiler

I used it for small project during school and it worked great.

http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It looks good, but according to the documentation : "Generate code for the Microchip PIC 14-bit processors (p16f84 and variants. In development, not complete)."
Since I am targeting pic16f88x family ....

Comment: I think PIC16s /are/ a 14-bit family.  I've used SDCC on a the 40-pin PIC16F871.

Comment: I think this is the only real answer to OPs question

Answer (score 7):

I am mentioning the PIC C compilers here, which are best when it comes to PIC Microcontroller Programming.

1. MPLAB C18 Compiler
2. MikroC Pro for PIC
3. CCS Compiler for PIC

You can read more about them on this post [Top 3 PIC C Compiler](http://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2016/02/pic-c-compiler.html), they have given a comparison between these 3 PIC Compilers i.e. there advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Probably the simplest way to start programming PIC microcontrollers is use Microchip's tools: MPLABX IDE and XC8, XC16 or XC32 compilers in free mode.

Answer (score 5):

[Mikroelektronika](http://www.mikroe.com) has a series of compilers, including Pascal and C with very good libraries for most of the stuff you'll need, such as CompactFlash, USB, LCD and etc.

It's not free, but the free version has enough juice to allow you do to most of the basic stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I recently got started with PIC c programming, and had some success with the lite version (free, but not open-source) of the Hi-Tech C compiler. I was using the PIC16F690 so it should work well for you too.

You  can download the compiler here:

http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en542849

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the sourceboost c compiler? 
This isn't open source but there is a free cost version details [here](http://www.sourceboost.com/Products/BoostC/Overview.html). It seems to work very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the CC5X C Compiler from http://www.bknd.com/cc5x/ it has an free edition too.
There is the hi-tech c compiler lite from microchip available [here](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en542849)