# how can i run the program on pic 18f2550

Tags: c, microcontroller

I wrote a program with c and  compile it, I used the mingw.Now I need run the program on pic 18f2550!I've never worked with microcontroller.What should I do?

Comment: I personnally use the MPLABX platform and C18 (LITE version). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185221/free-pic-c-compiler and http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/family/mplabx/ and http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en534868 and a Pickit2 (now 3) programmer

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't run the object file you have directly on your PIC. 
Your PC and microcontroller don't have the same architecture.

So you need to compile your code with the right compiler. 
I advise you to install MPLAB for free here : https://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en_us/devtools/mplabxc/

The IDE comes with the great compiler.

Also, you must have a JTAG programmer to put your firmware onto the PIC...

Comment: Maybe a better link to download the IDE directly.. And not the compiler

 http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en019469&part=SW007002

Comment: Can I use c code in MPLAB?is it similar with gcc?i first use Mikroc but i can't compile my code.

Comment: Yes you can.
I looked for your PIC in MPLAB and you will need C18 compiler.
Create a project using the wizard...

I personnally don't have C18 compiler. If you don't, you can find it here : http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en010014&redirects=c18

Put .exe file in Program Files/Microchip/MPLAB C18/ and look for them with the wizard..

Comment: C18 compiler is enough?i don't need anything?like header,library or any application?